# Displaying Empty Combobox content in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a User Control page (SubPODetailView.xaml) that contains some entities "**that entities defined from SubPO.cs**" and a datagridview "**that gridview is a separated class called SubInvoice.cs**", and everything went good but in the datagridview, one of entities is a combobox display, the problem here is the collection list of this combobox is not displayed when running a program.

> **SubPO.cs**

```
public class SubInvoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string InvoiceName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public List<string> Status{ get; set; }

    public int SubPOId { get; set; }

    public SubPO SubPO { get; set; }
}
```

> **Configuration.cs** (In Migration Folder)

```
context.SubInvoices.AddOrUpdate(i => i.InvoiceName,
            new SubInvoice
            {
                InvoiceName = "Invoice1",
                Date = new DateTime(2020, 5, 26),
                Amount = 1200,
                SubPOId=context.SubPOs.First().Id,
                Status = new List<string>() { "Open", "Closed", "Pending" }
            });
```

> **SubPODetailViewModel.cs**

```
 <DockPanel Grid.Row="12" Margin="10">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="86">
            <Button Content="Add"  Margin="10"
            Command="{Binding AddInvoiceCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Remove"  Margin="10"
            Command="{Binding RemoveInvoiceCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Invoices}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInvoice,Mode=TwoWay}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >
            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoices" Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding InvoiceName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Status,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

> **SubPODetailViewModel.cs**(Model)

```
    namespace SubBV.UI.ViewModel
{
    public class SubPODetailViewModel : DetailViewModelBase, ISubPODetailViewModel
    {
        private ISubPORepository _subPORepository;
        private IMessageDialogService _messageDialogService;
        private SubPOWrapper _subPO;
        private SubInvoiceWrapper _selectedInvoice;

        public SubPODetailViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            IMessageDialogService messageDialogService,
            ISubPORepository subPORepository) : base(eventAggregator)
        {
            _subPORepository = subPORepository;
            _messageDialogService = messageDialogService;

            AddInvoiceCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAddInvoiceExecute);
            RemoveInvoiceCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnRemoveInvoiceExecute, OnRemoveInvoiceCanExecute);

            Invoices = new ObservableCollection<SubInvoiceWrapper>();

        }

        public SubPOWrapper SubPO
        {
            get { return _subPO; }
            private set
            {
                _subPO = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public SubInvoiceWrapper SelectedInvoice
        {
            get { return _selectedInvoice; }
            set
            {
                _selectedInvoice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                ((DelegateCommand)RemoveInvoiceCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddInvoiceCommand { get; }
        public ICommand RemoveInvoiceCommand { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<SubInvoiceWrapper> Invoices { get; }

        public override async Task LoadAsync(int? subPOId)
        {
            var subPO = subPOId.HasValue
                ? await _subPORepository.GetByIdAsync(subPOId.Value)
                : CreateNewSubPO();
            InitializeSubInvoice(subPO.Invoices);
        }

    private void InitializeSubInvoice(ICollection<SubInvoice> invoices)
    {
        foreach (var wrapper in Invoices)
        {
            wrapper.PropertyChanged -= SubInvoiceWrapper_PropertyChanged;
        }
        Invoices.Clear();
        foreach (var subInvoice in invoices)
        {
            var wrapper = new SubInvoiceWrapper(subInvoice);
            Invoices.Add(wrapper);
            wrapper.PropertyChanged += SubInvoiceWrapper_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void SubInvoiceWrapper_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HasChanges)
        {
            HasChanges = _subPORepository.HasChanges();
        }
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SubInvoiceWrapper.HasErrors))
        {
            ((DelegateCommand)SaveCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeSubPO(SubPO subPO)
    {
        SubPO = new SubPOWrapper(subPO);
        SubPO.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!HasChanges)
            {
                HasChanges = _subPORepository.HasChanges();
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SubPO.HasErrors))
            {
                ((DelegateCommand)SaveCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        };
        ((DelegateCommand)SaveCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        if (SubPO.Id == 0)
        {
            // Little trick to trigger the validation
            SubPO.Title = "";
        }
    }
}
```

> **SubInvoiceWrapper.cs** (Wraps what is contained in the DataGridView)

```
public class SubInvoiceWrapper:ModelWrapper<SubInvoice>
{
    public SubInvoiceWrapper(SubInvoice model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public string InvoiceName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }

    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return GetValue<DateTime>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }

    }
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return GetValue<decimal>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }

    }
    public List<string> Status
    {
        get { return GetValue<List<string>>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }

    }
}
```

> ViewModelBase.cs (contains the propertychanged)

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of running program as shown the combobox is EMPTY!]

Comment: Maybe you can try to reduce the code the minimum needed to reproduce the issue? Your problem is hard to copy-paste for us trying to help.

Comment: The complexity of the code doesn't allow me to diagnose the issue. Did you check the `Status` value in debugger? Are there 3 blank items in the dropdown or is it empty? Is the `PropertyChanged` event fired when you change the `Status` property? Is `GetValue<>` method supports complex objects? Give some debugging details please. There's no explicit error in the shown code but some important logical parts are missing e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: @aepot, I updated the codes above and I added the PropertyChanged Code. The dropdown when I debug its empty.

Comment: `get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<string>>(); }` set a break point here and look, what will `GetValue` return. I think it returns `null`.

Comment: @aepot, I did that and yes it is null.

Comment: Inspect why then. Maybe that's happen inside the `GetValue` method.

Comment: @aepot, this is the line for GetValue,                                                                                                                                                                                       
 **protected virtual TValue GetValue<TValue>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            return (TValue)typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(Model);
        }**

Comment: Oh, Reflection. Super slow solution in terms of performance. But for now have no idea why it doesn't work. Look through debugger, compare Reflection behavior between this and other properties. Side note: Are you really need `ObservableCollection` there? Do you add/remove items while `DataGrid` is showing it? Change to `List` if not, it's faster.

Comment: @aepot Yes Iam adding rows or remove it as shown above in pic

Comment: @Maya rows in `DataGrid` - ok. But items in `ComboBox`? Why `ObservableCollection`? That's not related to the problem but a tip.

Comment: @aepot , I updated the code above as a List for combobox and I run but still no values there, can you check for me the updated codes above for "List"? Thanks.

Comment: Try `public IList Status {  get { return GetValue<IList>(); } ...` (not sure if it may help) Once again, try to debug it, even use step-by-step execution. Shown code doesn't contain any reason for that error.

Comment: @aepot, I did that but in the Configuration.cs class that already shown above, when I wrote  `Status = new IList { "Open", "Closed", "Pending" }` , There is an error occur says that Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IList'.

Comment: No, don't change this line, change everywhere else. `IList ... = new List<string> ...` - correct pattern. `IList` is just an interface that `List` class implements.

Comment: @aepot, Can you check for me if the code is correct because there is some error. **SubInvoice.cs:**  `public  List<string> Status{ get; set; }`,          **Configuration.cs:**  `IList Status = new List<string> { "Open", "Closed", "Pending" }` **SubInvoiceWrapper:** `public IList <List<string>> Status {   get { return GetValue<IList<List<string>>>(); }
 set { SetValue(value); }}`

Comment: `public IList Status { get; set; }`, `Status = new List<string> { "Open", "Closed", "Pending" }`
`public IList Status { get { return GetValue<IList>(); }  set { SetValue(value); }}`, don't forget to add `using System.Collections;`.

Comment: @aepot, I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work I will check, anyway thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @aepot,  I have another question related to this situation, I want to create a textbox that sums every added Amount which located in datagridview so shall I ask new question or its fine?

Comment: @Maya ask new..